# React JS Get State Value from another State

Tags: reactjs

I am using **React JS** and currently I want to performing action as below:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.state = {
          Final: 0,
          TotalCount: 30,
        };
}

function = () => {
this.setState({Final: (this.state.TotalCount / 10) +1 });
}
```

Well, I expected my outcomes of `Final` will be `4` but it is `1`
Is it my syntax error, or I can't perform operation like this?
(Apologies with ridiculous syntax since my based is in C#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess that you are calling `setState` in the constructor, right after declaring the state, and not at `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount() { this.setState({Final: (this.state.TotalCount / 10) +1 }) }
```

Be aware that because `setState` is async call (it isn't run immediately but tells the component it should render again with a new state), if there is some stuff that relies on state, you should manipulate them at next life cycle for assuring that the state updated before

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following syntax to access state while setting the state itself:

```
this.setState((state) => ({Final: (state.TotalCount / 10) +1 }))
```

As explained here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: hi, actually I declare `Final` and `TotalCount` at my `constructor` so I think I should use `this.state` instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
this.setState(prev => ({ ...prev, Final: parseInt(prev.TotalCount / 10) + 1 }))
```

`setState` basically takes callback which returns the updated state from the current state, also since division is there, so safely dividing to get integer and return the updated state.

Comment: setState basically takes callback which returns the updated state from current state, also since division is there, so safely dividing to get integer and return the updated state.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this as well:

```js
this.setState(prevState => {

  prevState.Final = (this.state.TotalCount/10) + 1;

  return {
    ...prevState.Final
  };
});
```

Comment: Brother, It's absolutely correct syntax. You can run this on [ReactBaseFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/) to check.

Comment: yea it is correct and it will run properly but according to convention no one follows this way of setting component state. i was just giving advice.